# call controller with ajax in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In ruby on rails project, when I create a reporter successfully, page is redirect to another action from another controller; and when the page is redirect, the page is reloaded. In this project, I have 2 controller:

reporters_controller.rb:

```
class ReportersController < ApplicationController
  layout "reporter"

  def new
    @reporter = Reporter.new
    @gomrokaddresses = Gomrokaddress.find(:all)
  end

  def create
    @reporter = Reporter.new(reporter_params)
    if @reporter.save
      #redirect_to new_reporter_path
      redirect_to new_problem_path(:id => @reporter.id)
    else
      @existreporter = Reporter.find_by(params[:rep_user_name])
      redirect_to new_problem_path(:id => @existreporter.id)
    end
  end
```

problems_controller.rb

```
def new
    @reporter = Reporter.find(params[:id])
    @problem = @reporter.problems.build
  end

  def create
    @reporter = Reporter.find(params[:id])
    @problem = @reporter.problems.build(problem_params)

    if @problem.save
      redirect_to new_problem_path(:id => @reporter.id)
    else
      redirect_to new_problem_path(:id => @reporter.id)
    end
  end
```

reporter.rb

```
class Reporter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :problems
end
```

problem.rb

```
class Problem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reporter
end
```

I create reporter and problem with `form_for` in view. When I complete `form_for` in `new.html.erb` (for reporter) and submit, create action (that exist in reporter_controller) is called, and then if information are true, page is redirect to `/problems/new`. Because of this `redirect_to`, the page is reload; I don't want reload the page, just when I create the reporter, the `form_for` of reporter replace with the `form_for` of problem. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller

```
redirect_to new_problem_path(:id => @reporter.id), format: 'js'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I use this code,but the page is reload again; I think the page is reload because of the url is change.

Answer (score 0):

A controller action renders the corresponding view template by default. Here, the action "problems#new" [automatically renders](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html) "views/problems/new.html.erb".

In your code, you've redirected to the URL represented by new_problem_path, and a GET request to that URL is routed to the "problems#new" action. Thus, the action is invoked and its template is loaded.

However, there are ways to [override this default behavior](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#creating-responses) if you want to call the action without loading the view template.

Also, `redirect_to` is different from AJAX. For AJAX, you'd use something like

```
def create
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    if @reporter.save
      format.html { redirect_to ... }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render action: ... }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

and then add the option `:remote => true` to `form_for` in the form that you use to create the new reporter.

But I'm not sure if this would accomplish what you're trying to do. Could you please explain your question further?

Comment: OK. So you're saying that when you submit the first form, it should use AJAX to display the second form. What should happen when you submit the second form?